# local OS access to VirtualBox server

Tags: networking, virtualbox, network-adapter

I have CentOS installed on my server. Next, I set up Ubuntu/mint 14.04 on a VirtualBox which is now on the CentOS server.

The CentOS server I can access through browser e.g. my.server.com:8080. How can I now forward the request to the VirtualBox?

Thank you in advance.

Mic

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you have the network adapter configured, but it's most likely that you're using NAT mode, so I'll focus on that.  The instructions for setting up NAT port forwarding are [here, see section 6.3.1](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html).

You can configure this through the management GUI, or the following command should do the trick:

```
VBoxManage modifyvm "VM name" --natpf1 "guestWeb,tcp,,8080,,8080"
```

Obviously you need to replace `VM name` with the actual name of your VM.

Alternatively, you could set the network adapter mode to "Bridged" to remove the need for NAT. The guest server will then be attached to the same network as the host. More info is available on that in the link I provided above.